# Change destination file name in VS SETUP project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

How can I change the file name on the destination folder in a VS setup project for primary output??

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean where the files are installed to, or what they are named?

Comment: Wondering if you are still having trouble with this? My answer below worked for me, so I expect it would work for you unless I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the tag, I'm assuming VS 2010: 
In the .vdproj file for the setup project, go to the "Product" section and change the value for "ProductName". Don't know why this isn't exposed in the IDE, at least I haven't seen a place where it is. This is the value used to replace [ProductName] in the *Right Click on Setup Project in Solution Explorer | View | File System | Application Folder | DefaulLocation* property.